# How to open TippyJS tooltip on click of a button elsewhere on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tippyjs

I am trying to open a tippy tooltip when a button is clicked, not append the tooltip to this button but open it in it's own spot.

In my example I have an add to cart button and a shoppingcart icon in my menu that shows the shopping cart inside a tippy tooltip. I want this tooltip to also show when clicking the add to cart button.

I've tried to create an instance of my tippy and use this with the `show()` method but I have no luck.

So as a simple example: there is element1 and element2. Element1 has the tippy code which works fine, but now I also want to trigger the tippy on element1 when clicking element2.

My code:

```
const tippyinstance = tippy('.carttip', {
  theme: 'blue',
  trigger: 'click',
  allowHTML: true,
  animation: 'scale-subtle',
  maxWidth: 400,
  boundary: 'viewport',
  interactive: true,
  content: function (reference) {
    return reference.querySelector('.tooltipcontent');
  },
  onShow(instance) {
    refreshcart(true, instance);
  }
});
```

My add to cart code:

```
$('body').on('click', ".addtocart", function (e, tippyinstance) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form_data = $(".addtocartform").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:"includes/addtocart.php",
    data: { form_data: form_data },
    success:function(data){
      tippyinstance.show();
    },
  });
});
```

I also have this function to always refresh the contents of the tooltip so the latest information is shown:

```
function refreshcart(force, tippyInstance) {
  $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'includes/refreshcart.php',
      data: ({}),
      success: function(data){
          $('body #headercart').empty().append(data);
          tippyInstance.popperInstance.update();
      }
  });
}
```

I tried passing `tippyinstance` to my add to cart function but I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'show')
```

Show is a correct method if you look at the docs :https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/methods/  So it probably cannot find my tippy instance. Why is that?

Opening the tooltip regularly works fine (clicking the shopping cart icon), just not when clicking the add to cart button.

Logging `console.log({tippyinstance})` inside my click function:

```
{tippyinstance: Array(1)}
tippyinstance: Array(1)
0: {id: 1, reference: div.carttip.module-icon.module-icon-cart, popper: div#tippy-1, popperInstance: null, props: {…}, …}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: `$('body').on('click', ".addtocart", function (e, tippyinstance) {` have you tried with only e as a param? Also add a `console.log({tippyinstance})` right below - what does it print?

Comment: @F.Müller If I remove that I get: `tippyinstance.show is not a function`. I added what is logged in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `triggerTarget` property:

```js
tippy(targets, {
  triggerTarget: null,                          // default (reference is used)
  triggerTarget: someElement,                   // Element
  triggerTarget: [someElement1, someElement2],  // Element[]
});
```

You can use it like this:

```js
tippy('.add', {content: 'locate the cart'});

tippy('.cart', {
  triggerTarget: [...document.querySelectorAll('.add')],
  trigger: 'click',
  content: ' Hey! ',
  animation: 'tada',
  theme: 'forest'
});

tippy('.cart', {content: 'checkout'});
```

```css
body {
  background: wheat;
}

.cart {
  position: fixed;
  right: 5rem;
  bottom: 2rem;
  color: green;
}

/* add custom animation */
.tippy-box[data-animation=tada] {
  animation: tada 1s linear 3;
  filter: contrast(1.5);
}

/* add custom theme */
.tippy-box[data-theme~='forest'] {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #6bbb62, #c4e466);
  color: black;
}

.tippy-box[data-theme~='forest']>.tippy-arrow::before {
  border-top-color: #81df76;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6/dist/tippy-bundle.umd.js"></script>

<div class="cart">
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
</div>
Item 1: <button class="add">Add</button><br><br> Item 2: <button class="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I already fixed it with this line: `tippyinstance[0].show()`, I had to add `[0]` for the method to work for some reason but I will accept your answer because this works too and the info is a bit more extensive.

Comment: The constructor `tippy('.add',{})` creates separate tooltip instances for each `.add` element, and returns array of them. So if you have 3 add buttons, with `class='add'` then it'll create 3 tippy instances. Using `triggerTarget` saves you from extra work of showing it yourself.